# Feeling A Bad Design Layout Using Segues

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

So I'm on my first iPhone app. I'm actually rather far into it. I have already learned from many mistakes, but I feel I've made an ultimate mistake. I'm using segues to navigate to different views. I get into about 5 segue views deep, which I'm realizing is causing a LOT of allocated memory. In other words, View A calls View B, B segues into C, C into D, etc..From what I understand, by the time I get to D I now have instances of A B C and D open, which does not sound good. I am using delegates for example like below:

Just an example of what I'm doing throughout my app:

First View:

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController<SecondViewControllerDelegate>

@end
```

Second View:

```
@class SecondViewController;

@protocol SecondReviewOrderViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

 - (void)secondViewControllerDidCancel:(SecondViewController *)controller;

@end

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController<ThirdViewControllerDelegate>
  @property (strong, nonatomic) id <SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

Third View:

@class ThirdViewController;

```
@protocol ThirdReviewOrderViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

 - (void)thirdViewControllerDidCancel:(ThirdViewController *)controller;

@end

@interface ThirdViewController : UIViewController<>
  @property (strong, nonatomic) id <ThirdViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

And so on and on onto view 4 and 5.

My question is, if this is wrong, which it seems to be, what is the right way to about navigating views and passing data from one viewcontroller to another? Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Normally a few viewcontroller instances would not be a memory problem but this is very app dependent. Do you actually have a problem with the memory of the view controller instances? Have you run your app in Allocations and seen a problem with memory pressure? Or is this just premature optimisation?

Comment: I have ran xcode instruments and seen pretty high allocations going into deep segues. Also I do not use NavigationControllers, I just use ViewControllers

Comment: Basically, I'm uploading videos to a server in View D, and I'm having some random upload problems where the upload just stalls and hangs and reports no errors or timeouts. I wondering if all this allocated memory has to do with it.

Comment: I think you're barking up the proverbial wrong tree, there, @TMan - an upload stall sounds like a networking issue, not a memory issue. If you have a memory issue, you'll know: you'll get memory warnings (on the device - be sure to test on the device).

Comment: By the way this sounds like a pretty impressive first iPhone app! My first iPhone app did nothing but sing "99 Bottles of Beer on the Wall" (and it still does).

Comment: haha, thx. Yea I'm getting memory warnings once in a while so I need to try to see where this is happening and try to let go some of this memory. I'm using ARC though, thought that was his job.

Comment: @TMan - Glad you solved your question. As an aside, tho, I'd suggest that you make your `delegate` references weak. You want to avoid strong reference cycles. You generally don't want something lower in the hierarchy maintaining strong references to something higher in the hierarchy. You might not have a retain cycle, but you're opening yourself up for one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From what I understand, by the time I get to D I now have instances of A B C and D open, which does not sound good

A view controller, of itself, is a fairly lightweight object, and there is no problem whatever with going many levels deep (e.g. pushing five view controllers onto a navigation controller stack). However, memory and images you may be holding on to are not lightweight, so be sure to implement `didReceiveMemoryWarning` and take it seriously if it arrives.

A strategy for letting go of large retained memory-hogging stuff in response to `didReceiveMemoryWarning` is to save it off to disk (if it can't be recreated on demand) and then use lazy initialization to read it back in the next time you are asked for it.

Comment: Right, exactly. I do have videos being stored in the temp directory which is where all the allocation is coming from. I have been getting memory warning, But how do I deal with this?

Comment: Storage on disk in the temp directory is not going to give you a memory warning. The memory warning is about stuff you are retaining in, say, an instance variable. That is the stuff you need to let go of if you get a warning.

Comment: I am assuming here, of course, that you are using ARC so that there is hardly any chance that you are *mismanaging* memory (i.e. leaking).

Comment: on my instruments, For All Allocations: Live Bytes: 5.38MB, Overall Bytes: 22.16MB, Does this sound normal?

Comment: And during the upload process, it gets up to around 10MB. Well you've certainly made me feel better about this part of my app. Thanks for your help. I'm sure Apple will find something wrong with it though.

Comment: A temporary rise to 10MB is still nothing to worry about. As Robotic Cat suggested, don't optimize prematurely. There'll be time enough for counting when the dealing's done!

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the advice